# JPA - inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Class Hierarchy:

```
| Vehicle
+ - Motorized
+ - - Truck
```

Database tables - putting the Vehicle fields in Motorized table but keeping Motorized and Truck as separate tables:

Motorized - has Vehicle fields
Truck - FK to Motorized

Is there a simple way to do this in `JPA`?

e.g. such that the following can be used:

```
EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
Query q = em.createQuery("select t from Todo t");
List<Vehicle> vehicles = q.getResultList();
```

Can polymorphism be achieved with the find method?

```
Vehicle vehicle = em.find(Vehicle.class, 123);
```

Comment: You mean putting the Motorized fields in the Vehicle table?  Motorized is more specialized version of Vehicle ... Hmmm, maybe some more info?  This is a great site btw : http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence

Comment: Typo:  Query q = em.createQuery("select v from Vehicle");

Comment: Look at Inheritance: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance Additionally, using the Criteria approach to querying is type safe, whereas JPQL is not, afik.

Comment: Right - had motorized, vehicle reversed - same question, though: if A -- B -- C represent a class hierarchy (B from A, C from B) and want only tables B and C (with A's fields in B table) then -- it looks like mapped-superclass will do it but w/ restrictions -- i'm going to look for other solutions, too

Comment: Show us your class diagram, pls, not sure if Vehicle is parent class

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for JPA [joined inheritance](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#Joined.2C_Multiple_Table_Inheritance).

I'm not absolutely sure if you'll get polymorphism with the find method, but I would think so, since Hibernate maintains a first-level cache of all its objects, by ID; and if you requested that object by its ID, it would have to return an instance of the appropriate subclass.

Comment: joined inheritance by itself doesn't seem to handle the case where the root class of the hierarchy is not in a separate table.  It looks like mapped-superclass is one way (along w/ joined inheritance).  I'll look further.